# Is there a word to describe something that is only capable of doing one thing?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Something like a one-trick pony. In a limitation type of context. Unique ability, but it is the only ability capable of being done, so it is unique to itself.

Comment: Single-function.

Comment: Is this to describe a machine, a tool, or another piece of equipment; or is it to describe a person or animal? If it's a piece of equipment it can be described as 'dedicated', for instance "The packing department PC has a _dedicated_ label printer attached to it. Such a printer may be designed only to print labels or it may be a general-purpose printer used only for that purpose and loaded only with adhesive label feedstock. Describing a _person_ as 'dedicated' means something else.

Comment: The OP never responded to whether this is a person or not. If it's a person, an *idiot savant* does many things poorly but can do a specific task brilliantly (perhaps calculating the day of the week in 1960).

Answer (score 0):

> [uni-tasker](https://www.npr.org/sections/thesalt/2015/12/23/460833325/the-unitasker-kitchen-gadgets-alton-brown-loves-to-loathe)

There’s a cooking show called Good Eats, where the host, Alton Brown, will often rail against what he calls “uni-taskers.” As opposed to multitaskers, uni-taskers are rarely worth the space they take up due to their limited usefulness.

It’s not a real word, but fans of the show would at least understand you, and in context so would others.

Answer (score 0):

Not a single word but - **special purpose**